# JMeter with Yaml file (AWS Distribution Testing)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, yaml

I have question can we call the variables from yaml(.yml) file into JMeter ? As I am facing an issue.

The reason to use YAML(.yml) file instead of .properties file is that our script is running fine in local when we pass the variables i.e Numbers of user , in config.properties file but when we run in AWS distribution testing we are getting an issue . So I am trying with YML . As someone suggested but how to call the variables in JMeter of yml . We are facing an challenge . Any Idea or any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see how YAML file will help there.

If you have `config.properties` file you can "feed" it to the JMeter Slaves as follows:

1. Either start JMeter slave process providing the path to the `config.properties` file using `-q` command-line argument
2. Or pass the `config.properties` file from the master machine to the slaves using `-G` command-line argument

More information:

- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

If by "AWS Distribution Testing" you mean [Distributed Load Testing on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/) then check out [JMeter Properties and Variables](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables) article of [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) documentation